# Need help implementing error handler

Tags: error-handling

I'm trying to implement an error handler. It's a helper that checks if there's an error code in `$?` variable and exits the script with a code and a message.

The code below is quite simple and self-explaining, but it's not working and I can't understand what's going on at all. I've tried passing `$?` as an argument to this function, but it doesn't work also. What am I missing?

```
#!/bin/bash

#this line causes error "asd: command not found"
asd

exit_if_error () {
  ERROR_STATUS="$1"
  ERROR_TEXT="$2"
  if [ "$?" != "0" ]; then
    # prints an error message on standard error and terminates the script with an exit status
    echo "$ERROR_TEXT" 1>&2
    exit "$ERROR_STATUS"
  fi
}

exit_if_error "1" "Something bad happened"

echo "No errors during execution"
```

This also doesn't work

```
#!/bin/bash

#this line causes error "asd: command not found"
asd

exit_if_error () {
  ERROR="$1"
  ERROR_STATUS="$2"
  ERROR_TEXT="$3"
  if [ "$ERROR" != "0" ]; then
    # prints an error message on standard error and terminates the script with an exit status of 1
    echo "$ERROR_TEXT" 1>&2
    exit "$ERROR_STATUS"
  fi
}

exit_if_error "$?" "1" "Something bad happened"

echo "No errors during execution"
```

How do you handle errors in your scripts? Do you write code similar to this? I'm just trying to find a less verbose solution.

```
command_a
if [ "$?" != "0" ]; then
  echo "command_a failed..." 1>&2
  exit 1
fi

command_b
if [ "$?" != "0" ]; then
  echo "command_b failed..." 1>&2
  exit 1
fi

...
```

Comment: `$ERROR` isn't set somewhere?

Comment: @bac0n, sorry, that line isn't supposed to be there. Edited the code.

Comment: this will not work ... $? contains the exit code from the "last" executed command. Not sure it's probably the function call `exit_if_error` the `if` statement also produce an exit code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `trap` to intercept the error signal.

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

ERROR=0
error_handling(){
    ((ERROR > 0)) &&
    printf %s\ %s\\n "$1" "$2"
    exit $ERROR
}
trap "ERROR=1" ERR

jdshfsduoifh

error_handling 1 "PANIC error!"
```

Bash has a built-in function for handling missing commands

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

command_not_found_handle(){
    echo "Command '$@' not found, please install me!"
}

jdshfsduoifh
```

If you really want to silence messages, you can redirect stderr to `/dev/null`.

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

exec 3>&2 2>/dev/null

# This error will be
# redirected to /dev/null
ls nonexistant_1
(($? > 0)) &&
echo "Error: this isn't right!"

# Let's restore our old descriptor.
exec 2>&3 3>&-

ls nonexistant_2
exit
```

Stderr may already have a descriptor assigned; example `script.sh 2> file.log`, using exec to manipulate the descriptor of the current shell, we first need to duplicate stderr to a new descriptor before assigning `/dev/null` to stderr, it allows for restoring the old *descriptor*.

Comment: sir, thank you very much!

Comment: quick question, is there a way to prevent the original error message from being displayed on the terminal? `grfsd: command not found`

Comment: just change `echo "command ...."` line to a `:` to suppress "command not found"